# Most up-to-date packages for Machine Learning in R: Lasso, Random Forest, Neural Nets

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network, random-forest, glmnet

I'm reaching out to the community to see what the most up-to-date packages are for implementing Lasso, RF, and NN in R.

**Lasso**

As far as I know, `lars` has been replaced by `glmnet` for lasso and ridge regression. I think `glmnet` is the most cutting-edge package. http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/index.html

**Random Forest**

Until now I've used the package Breiman and Cutler's `randomforest.` http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/index.html

I believe there is a new package called `party` by Hothorn, Hornik, Strobl, and Zeileis, where `cforest()` implements Breiman's random forests. I haven't used it yet. http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/party/index.html

**Neural Nets**

For neural nets, Guenther's `neuralnet` package was just released on Aug. 29, 2013. Although I haven't used it to speak to whether it's currently considered as the best choice for NN.  http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/neuralnet/neuralnet.pdf

Comment: You might want to check out the [CRAN Machine Learning Task View](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MachineLearning.html). It was last update on 2013-07-31, and so doesn't yet include `neuralnet`; if you are interested in contributing that or other pointers to the Task View, that page includes the email address of the Task View's maintainer...